# lock ftp user in home directory

Tags: ftp, chroot

I have read, researched, tested, and still cannot seem to get this working correctly.
I am running VSFTPD on Debian.  With a test account configured to point the user's home directory to a mount point which actually resides on a NAS share, for example /home/ftp/NAS/UserHomeFolder, after connecting I can change directories to the root directory of the Linux Server and navigate to the etc folder, usr, and so forth.
In my vsftpd.conf file I have chroot_local_user=YES, the chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list option is enabled and the account I am using is listed in the vsftpd.chroot_list file.  With regard to PAM, I have pam_service_name=vsftpd.
ssl_enable=YES, allow_anon_ss=NO, force_local_data_ssl=YES, force_local_logins_ssl=YES.
If I use chsh -s /bin/nologin secureftptestaccount (I added the /bin/nologin to the shells list) I get access denied when attempting to connect to the FTP Server.
So, what am I missing here?
Thanks in advance for your help and insight.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `chroot_local_user=YES` the effect of the `chroot_list_file=` reverses, it becomes a list of users who are NOT confined to chroot.

So remove the username of your test account from /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list and you should be fine.

A quick check with `man vsftpd.conf` would have explained that:

**chroot_list_enable**

> If activated, you may provide a list of local users who are placed in
>   a chroot() jail in their home directory upon login. The meaning is
>   slightly different if chroot_local_user is set to YES. In this case,
>   the list becomes a list of users which are NOT to be placed in a
>   chroot() jail. By default, the file containing this list is
>   /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list, but you may override this with the
>   chroot_list_file setting.